# What's the difference between Enumerative Combinatorics and Analytic Combinatorics? With Example?

Tags: combinatorics

Can you explain what's the difference between Enumerative and Analytic Combinatorics? with an example?

Answer (score 3):

Enumerative combinatorics just refers to techniques for counting things.  Analytic combinatorics generally refers to the application of real or complex analysis, often via generating functions, to combinatorial problems.

An important application of analytic methods is to derive asymptotic expressions for sequences, often by analyzing the behavior of the generating function near its singularities. Flajolet and Odlyzko's [paper](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/2009-SS/flajolet-odlyzko.pdf) gives a good overview.